# Running a groupby agg function on multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Usually when you apply an aggregation on a single column, you do it like this:

```
def myfunc(x):
    return x.mean()

df.groupby('col').agg(named_agg = ('col1', myfunc))
```

In my case, my function `myfunc` needs values from two columns, something like this:

```
def myfunc(x, y):
    return (x + y).mean()

df.groupby('col').agg(named_agg = (['col1', 'col2'], myfunc))
```

I don't want to use apply, since this is just one of several aggregations which I'll be doing, and I want to include all in one command. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please provide your input and desired output.

Comment: It's not really about the input/output, rather usage of pandas groupby agg. However, I've added some explanation above